# What does "Danger!" mean?

Tags: splatoon-3

During a Turf War I noticed a light-green "Danger!" prompt appear at the top of the screen next to my team's status icons. What does the Danger! prompt mean?

[image: danger prompt]

Answer (score 5):

If it is still like that and [Reddit is correct](https://www.reddit.com/r/splatoon/comments/4juvtk/why_does_it_say_danger_at_the_top_of_the_screen/), that danger is that your team is getting led by 100 points or more.

Answer (score 4):

My observation of some gameplay leads me to believe this appears next to your teams icons when you are losing by a significant margin.  In this [gameplay video](https://youtu.be/m5fFNCTXLe4?t=827), you can see the opposing team has the Danger icon present, and when the score is revealed at the end, they lost by a significant amount.  From watching a few other videos, it seems to display when you have ~30% of the map covered or less, but I imagine it could be based off of some ratio between what your team has covered, and what the other team has covered.

Thus, if you see this symbol for your team, you better pull it together and make a comeback or you are going to lose!

Comment: The 30% figure seems inaccurate. I finished a game with the danger sign and had 38.4% vs 54.5%

Comment: @Stevoisiak that was more of just an observation - its probably somehow ratio based as I suggested.  It doesn't really matter though for the question at hand. 38% also isn't far off from ~30%